# If-statement evaluates incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

I have a Blazor/HTML page where a user can run queries against an API. There's 2 ways for a user to run the queries. The user can either input the data manually or he can take a picture containing the input data. Both options work just fine, however, when an image is taken and processed the Blazor for some reason doesn't want to render it. The if-statement evaluates to `false` each time even though it should evaluate to `true`.

```cs
@inherits QueryBase
@page "/query"

@inject NavigationManager navigator

<select class="bv-input" @bind="QueryType">
    @foreach(QueryType type in queryTypes){
        <option value="@type">@type.ToDisplayFormat()</option>
    }
</select>

@switch(QueryType){
    case QueryType.Basic:
    case QueryType.Technical:
    case QueryType.DetailedTechnical:
    case QueryType.Survey:
    case QueryType.Ownerships:
        <BasicQuery @ref="ActiveQuery"/>
        break;
    case QueryType.License:
        <LicenseQuery @ref="ActiveQuery" />
        break;
    case QueryType.Assesment:
        <AssesmentQuery @ref="ActiveQuery"/>
        break;
    case QueryType.Chassis:
        <ChassisQuery @ref="ActiveQuery"/>
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Shits on fire yo");
}

<input class="bv-input" type="button" value="Sök" @onclick="SearchAsync" />
<hr />

@if(Searching){
    <div class="spinner-overlay"></div>
}

<div class="bv-content">
    @if(QueryRenderer is not null){
        @QueryRenderer.Render()
    }
    else{
        <h3>NULL</h3>
    }

    <div class="bv-footer">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-gear bv-icon" @onclick="GoToSettings"></i>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public bool Searching { get; set; }

    public async Task SearchAsync()
    {
        if (!ActiveQuery.Validate(out string result))
        {
            await Dialog.AlertAsync("Någonting hände...", result);
            return;
        }

        Searching = true;
        try
        {
            await ActiveQuery.SearchAsync(QueryType);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            await Dialog.AlertAsync("Någonting hände...", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Searching = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task ScanAsync()
    {
        Searching = true;
        try
        {
            await ActiveQuery.ScanAsync(QueryType);
            await ActiveQuery.SearchAsync(QueryType);
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException) {} //We dont care about cancelled tasks
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            await Dialog.AlertAsync("Någonting hände...", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Searching = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So what happens is: the `ScanAsync` method is called, everything works as expected and when we reach `finally` and turn off `Searching`, this also works as expected. The UI re-renders and the spinner disappears. But the `QueryRenderer` does not render, for some reason the if-statement evaluates to `false` even when `QueryRenderer` is clearly not null. I've gone through the `ScanAsync` method with a breakpoint and it clearly states that it is not `null`. I've also tried calling `StateHasChanged` after turning off `Searching` but to no avail.

[image]

`ActiveQuery` related methods (`LicenseQuery`):

```cs
public async Task SearchAsync(QueryType type)
    {
        BaseDTO dto = await Web.FetchRestAsync<LicenseDTO>(type, SocialSecurityNumber.TrimSsn(), ValidityDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        IEnumerable<DTOPropertyInfo> info = await Settings.GetPropertiesInfoAsync(dto);

        RestResponse = new()
        {
            Error = dto.Error,
            Info = info
        };

        QueryRenderer = this;
    }

    public async Task ScanAsync(QueryType _)
    {
        LicenseData license = await Scanner.ScanLicenseAsync();
        SocialSecurityNumber = license.SocialSecurityNumber;
        ValidityDate = license.ValidityDate;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the if-statement?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It's in the first snippet of  code, located within the div with class ``bv-content``

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside the if statement (as far as I can remember that works in Blazor) to make sure the issue is with the containing page and not with the QueryRenderer? Or replace it with some raw html placeholder to check. Might also be helpful to supply QueryRenderer.Render(), I assume it returns a Renderfragment?

Comment: _But the QueryRenderer does not render, for some reason the if-statement evaluates to false even when QueryRenderer is clearly not null._ Does this mean that you still see `<h3>NULL</h3>` being rendered?

Comment: @noel Thanks for mentioning putting a breakpoint inside the if-statement. I never tried that since I thought that wouldn't work. To my surprise, the breakpoint was never triggered. Apparently I had forgotten to notify my parent view when a child view is doing the scanning part. Now everything is working as intended!

Comment: In the code blocks you've shown `QueryRenderer` is never defined.  You make references to it but never declare it.  I see `QueryRenderer = this;` which suggests it's the parent component, but that looks a pretty odd thing to do.
`

Comment: @Zita If your problem has already been resolved, you can post an answer so that more people can see and solve similar problems.

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT Aye captain! My bad, forgot about it. I'll post it in a moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement evaluates incorrectly simply because it never ran from the start. Since the user-input happened in a child view and the rendering happened in the parent view, the rendering doesn't happen automatically in the parent view because it has no idea what's happening outside of its own 'scope'. So to fix this, I created a public method in the parent view called `Refresh()` which calls `StateHasChanged()`. Then I simply pass in a reference to the parent view into the child view and once the scanning was done I just called `Parent.Refresh()` in order to update the parent view.